# Not able to convert date from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am doing an application where I am using the following link http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-3.html to convert the date from string.

I am using below code to same by following above tutorial link. when I `NSlog` `PresentDateTime` it gives  20120111 13:03:49.263+05:30.

so I am taking this format and want to convert into the format of "`EEEE MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a, zzz`".

To do so when I assign the same to the variable

> NSString *today = presentDateTime;

when I `NSLog` `Datestring` I am getting result `NULL` can I know where I am going wrong? please help me to solve this issue by suggesting what changes to be done

//code

```
 -(NSString *)DateFormat:(NSString *) presentDateTime

{


presentDateTime = [presentDateTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
presentDateTime = [presentDateTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" +" withString:@"+"];
presentDateTime = [presentDateTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"Present date::::%@",presentDateTime);

  NSString *today = presentDateTime;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:SSSZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:today];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a, zzz"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormat release];
NSLog(@"dateString:::Date>>>>:%@::::\n%@",dateString, presentDateTime);
return dateString;
```

Comment: Your date parsing pattern (`yyyyMMdd`) is incomplete, is that by intention? When you print `date` with `NSLog`, do you get a reasonable date or is it nil?

Comment: @crazy2431 don't you need to take the time into account due to timezone, otherwise you may get wrong date depending on timezone.

Comment: @DarkDust sorry that was not by intention i think i ddint add the proper format...wat format i shd add?i am not getting reasonable date when i nslog for datestring..its giving null

Comment: i have edited my code by changing date format

Comment: I found the remaining issue: `NSDateParser` has trouble with the colon in the timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date format pattern for parsing the date is wrong/incomplete. For the string `20120111 13:03:49.263+05:30` the format would be `YYYYMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ`. See [this table](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the format string patterns.

**Edit:** After playing around with the code, it turns out that the `NSDateParser` chokes on the timezone `+05:30`. It expects `+0530`, without the colon. Here's how to remove it:

```
    NSString *today = @"20120111 13:03:49.263+05:30";
    NSRange colon = [today rangeOfString:@":" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    if (colon.location != NSNotFound) {
        today = [today stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:colon withString:@""];
    }
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:today];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: Format pattern is correct and is not wrong. In mentioned table and in any other standard is never said to use full date format to convert string<->date.

Comment: @DarkDust i have changed the format as u mentioned in my above code..when i nslog for Datestring i am getting  still null

Comment: @Nekto: Try it for yourself: if the date format is incomplete then `dateFromString:` fails.

Comment: I know that it fails of course... But date format `yyyyMMdd` is quite complete...

Comment: @Nekto: No, it was not complete because the input string had additional information. You're simply assuming that the time is irrelevant and may be chopped off, but depending on the use case the time is very important and needs to be parsed as well (plus the time zone, of course).

Answer (score 1):

When you parse your original date string you need to specify the entire format, like this:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Compare your code with the following

```
NSString *dateString = @"6:30 18 Oct";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd/MMM"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Its just sample to follow. and figure out what is going wrong by printing it in nslog.

Comment: You're using a totally different date format than the poster, how is that going to help him?

Comment: Ya, its not the same format, but he/she can refer to it and try changing the format and see the results in nslog, thats why I have already said that its just sample.

Answer (score -2):

Your `date` variable is always nil because your date format (`yyyyMMdd`) is incomplete as your input string `today` contains extra information (`20120111 13:03:49.263+05:30`). So you can just crop unnecessary characters:

```
if ([presentDateTime count] < 8) return nil;
NSString *today = [presentDateTime substringToIndex:8];
```

Or you should specify full date format as mentioned by @jonkroll

Comment: This is a very bad idea: you're chopping off vital information instead of parsing it correctly!

Comment: This is normal idea if this informations is not needful..... I don't understand why he don't want just to convert input string and makes some replacements so...